# Warning when running a background java process (works fine though)

Tags: java, jar, daemon

I produced an executable jar and when I run it from the command line (iOS) a Java window opens which means the process isn't fully *background*. When I add the following option:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar MyJar.jar
```

It works as expected but gives me the following warning:

```
2017-03-12 16:48:07.743 java[45915:8158809] [JRSAppKitAWT markAppIsDaemon] failed. SetApplicationIsDaemon returned -50
```

Tried googling the warning but no luck. What does the warning mean? How to get rid of it? Is it ok to ignore it? If it failed then why does it work exactly as I wanted it?

Thanks